# Sendmail: Is there a way to configure a configure a "buffer" for Incoming Emails?

Tags: smtp, email-server, sendmail

My Sendmail server receives in average 30 mails/minute, but during some peak times this number jumps to  5000/minute. For processing logic reasons, I would like to know  if would be possible to set some kind of queuing in the Sendmail for the incoming emails that it handles only, lets say, 100 mails in a given moment, spreading the processing more homogeneously.

Kind Regards

Comment: You may be able to handle more mail at peak loads using queue only mode.  This seems to be set with "QueueLA ( x)" which sets a load average above which mail is only queued.   You may need to tune you queue runs as well.

Answer (score 1):

You have an option `CONNECTION_RATE_THROTTLE` but that simply rejects new incoming connections above a certain limit.
The downside of which is that then the mail is not queued by your sendmail, rather the sending mailserver gets a temporary delivery error and will simply have queue the message and make a second delivery attempt later.

In sendmail.cf M4 syntax:

```
define(`confCONNECTION_RATE_THROTTLE', `100')dnl
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but the downside is a show-stopper for me. 
I've not able to find anything on the internet. So maybe it is just not possible with sendmail.
cheers,